# CHOOSE.EXE replacement

Tags: windows, batch-file

Please consider my old script:

```
CHOOSE.EXE /c:ynq /t:n,7 " until 7 seconds press Y to smooth details "
set "LowPassFilter=0"
if errorlevel==255 echo No such choice (255)
if not errorlevel==4 if errorlevel==3 echo The choice was a q (3)
if not errorlevel==3 if errorlevel==2 echo LowPass OFF
if not errorlevel==2 if errorlevel==1 (Set LowPassFilter=1)
if not errorlevel==1 if errorlevel==0 echo The choice was interrupted (0)

IF "%LowPassFilter%"=="1" echo LowPassFiltering ATTIVATO per ammorbidire contorni
IF "%LowPassFilter%"=="1" Set "filteringVirtualdubMode=135"
IF "%LowPassFilter%"=="0" echo LowPassFiltering Disattivato
IF "%LowPassFilter%"=="0" Set "filteringVirtualdubMode=7"
```

but choose.exe is problematic for windows 10 64bit and I need to replace it with another command that does the same functions.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at the DOS-native `choice` command. Something like this should work:

```
choice /c:ynq /t:7 /d:n
IF errorlevel==...
```

`/d:n` is required and sets the default value after 7 seconds to `n`. Otherwise `/t` can't be used.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `XCOPY`, it can handle more characters than `choice`.
The only drawback is that it's more complex to implement a timeout

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

call :getKey
echo '!ch!'
exit /b

:getKey
set "ch="
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
for /f "delims=" %%C in ('2^>nul xcopy /w /l "%~f0" "%~f0"') do if not defined ch set "ch=%%C"
(  
endlocal
set "ch=^%ch:~-1%" !
)
exit /b
```

Answer (score 0):

Read `choice /?`. Use

```
choice  /c:ynq /t:7 /D:n /M:"until 7 seconds press Y to smooth details"
```

For  handling `errorlevel`, read `if /?`. Note that succession of `if errorlevel ...` commands matters (need to test `errorlevel` values in descending order).

```
choice  /c:ynq /t:7 /D:n /M:"until 7 seconds press Y to smooth details"
set "LowPassFilter=0"
if errorlevel 255 echo No such choice (255)&goto :next
if errorlevel 3 echo The choice was a q (3)&goto :next
if errorlevel 2 echo LowPass OFF&goto :next
if errorlevel 1 (Set "LowPassFilter=1"&goto :next)
if errorlevel 0 echo The choice was interrupted (0)

:next
IF "%LowPassFilter%"=="1" (
      echo LowPassFiltering ATTIVATO per ammorbidire contorni
      Set "filteringVirtualdubMode=135"
)
IF "%LowPassFilter%"=="0" (
      echo LowPassFiltering Disattivato
      Set "filteringVirtualdubMode=7"
)
```

Another approach (you could test `%errorlevel%` values in *any order* in next code snippet):

```
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions
choice  /c:ynq /t:7 /D:n /M:"until 7 seconds press Y to smooth details"
set "LowPassFilter=0"
if %errorlevel% EQU 255 echo No such choice (255)
if %errorlevel% EQU 3 echo The choice was a q (3)
if %errorlevel% EQU 2 echo LowPass OFF
if %errorlevel% EQU 1 (Set "LowPassFilter=1")
if %errorlevel% EQU 0 echo The choice was interrupted (0)

rem etc.
```

Testing `errorlevel` against `0` (zero) value is important as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> would bring another dialogue `Terminate batch job (Y/N)?` and

- `Y` terminates all script (batch job) rather than `choice` command while
- `N` sets `errorlevel` to `0` (zero) and the script continues.